# fb-login-button (html) triggers a popup that is blocked by the browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am struggling with a Facebook login popup being blocked by the browser. I am using the fb-login-button html code to initialize FB login process, as specified below:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="true" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true" data-scope="user_friends, email, public_profile"></div>
```

I am initializing facebook JS in a regular way as specified in the FB documentation:

```
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'myAppID',
          cookie     : true,
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.11'
        });

        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

        fbApiInit = true; //init flag 

      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    </script>
```

But whenever a user clicks the 'Continue with Facebook' button the popup gets blocked by the browser.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Does anyone has a suggested solution? (I am aware that browsers block popups if not directly prompted by the user but I struggle where should I even check/modify how the login process is triggered with the html fb-login-button)

EDIT
I have deployed a fragment of the site (login page) to a test URL within GAE: https://udacity-test-helloworld.appspot.com/login . If successful should redirect to a page with 'Test Main Page'.

Many, many thanks in advance,
Mateusz

Comment: what browser exactly? any installed plugins? do you have a test link for us?

Comment: Hi luschn, thank you for your response. I have observed the behaviour in IE11 as well as Chrome 62 (this is not coming from a comprehensive review but rather ad-hoc checks). I have edited the question to include a link to the login page with the html fb-login-button implemented.

Comment: Works fine for me in a current Chrome (62). IE 11 initially blocks it, but asks me how I want it handled in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers blocks client side popups untill you give the permission to open. You can use something like php-sdk to redirect the user in another blank page, making the same action (login), and that avoid the javascript popups blocking.
Blocking popups it is a browser features so, like luschn wrote in the comments you should rely on the browser.

heres the php-sdk for facebook: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk
heres the documentations: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

hope it helps ;)

Comment: chrome also blocks redirect